# Pycharm python console socket.gaierror

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm running Pycharm 4.5.3 on OS X Yosemite (10.10.3). I created a simple python program, and tried opening the python console, and got this stack trace error:

```
/usr/bin/python -u /Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevconsole.py 59286 59287
Error starting server with host: localhost, port: 59286, client_port: 59287
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function start_server at 0x100d9bd70>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevconsole.py", line 283, in start_server
    server = XMLRPCServer((host, port), logRequests=False, allow_none=True)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/SimpleXMLRPCServer.py", line 593, in __init__
    SocketServer.TCPServer.__init__(self, addr, requestHandler, bind_and_activate)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 419, in __init__
    self.server_bind()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 430, in server_bind
    self.socket.bind(self.server_address)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.gaierror: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known
Couldn't connect to console process.
```

A similar question was raised here on stack overflow, but the root of the error was the string localhost passed in with white spaces, which is not the case here (host has been assigned to 'localhost'). Does anyone have any idea? This isn't really a big deal, seeing as I can use python command line in terminal, but I'm curious if this is a bug within Pycharm.

Edit: here's the source code to the Pycharm script.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import pydevconsole
    sys.stdin = pydevconsole.BaseStdIn()
    port, client_port = sys.argv[1:3]
    import pydev_localhost

    if int(port) == 0 and int(client_port) == 0:
        (h, p) = pydev_localhost.get_socket_name()

        client_port = p

    pydevconsole.StartServer(pydev_localhost.get_localhost(), int(port), int(client_port))
```

Comment: Does '127.0.0.1' work?

Comment: could you also post the relevant parts of the program that is raising this exception.

Comment: @Totem This is the internal pycharm script for starting the pydev console, so I can't change the internal code. I looked at their source code in main, and I've posted that in the main code box.

Comment: @HaleemurAli This is all that is relevant to the program. It's a simple click in the PyCharm toolbar, which throws this. I have written no code myself which makes this happen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answers given so far do not get at the underlying cause, which is likely to be that your OS X `/etc/hosts` file does not contain an entry for: 127.0.0.1 localhost

Update the hosts file with the line:

`127.0.0.1 localhost`

(you will need to use sudo), then restart pyCharm. Unless you know what you are doing, editing your IDE source code is not a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

I'm new in python, stuck on the same problem for half a day. Finally solved this problem by setting the host to 127.0.0.1.
If you have the same issue you can do this by:

> 1. open pydevconsole.py in pycharm, navigate to the main script part and find this line:
>    `pydevconsole.StartServer(pydev_localhost.get_localhost(), int(port), int(client_port))`
> 2. ctrl + click the function `get_localhost()` to navigate to its source:
>
> `_cache = None def get_localhost():'''`
>
> Should return 127.0.0.1 in ipv4 and ::1 in ipv6

```
localhost is not used because on windows vista/windows 7, there can be issues where the resolving doesn't work
properly and takes a lot of time (had this issue on the pyunit server).

Using the IP directly solves the problem.
'''
#TODO: Needs better investigation!

global _cache
if _cache is None:
    try:
        for addr_info in socket.getaddrinfo("localhost", 80, 0, 0, socket.SOL_TCP):
            config = addr_info[4]
            if config[0] == '127.0.0.1':
                _cache = '127.0.0.1'
                return _cache
    except:
        #Ok, some versions of Python don't have getaddrinfo or SOL_TCP... Just consider it 127.0.0.1 in this case.
        _cache = '127.0.0.1'
    else:
        _cache = 'localhost'

return _cache
```

I believe the problem is caused by the returning "localhost" of this function, make it "127.0.0.1" solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue on OS X El Capitan, running Pycharm 2016.2.

In any editor open: `/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevconsole.py`

If you're navigating via Finder, right-click the Pycharm.app file and choose "Show Package Contents" to get access to the path.

Find the line:

```
pydevconsole.start_server(pydev_localhost.get_localhost(), int(port), int(client_port))
```

Change it to:

```
pydevconsole.start_server('127.0.0.1', int(port), int(client_port))
```

Restart Pycharm and choose Tools->Python Console...

You should then see:

```
Users/.../env/bin/python /Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevconsole.py 56582 56583
PyDev console: starting.


import sys; print('Python %s on %s' % (sys.version, sys.platform))
sys.path.extend(['/Users/...'])

Python 3.5.0 (default, Dec  1 2015, 12:50:23) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.1.76)] on darwin
```